# why adding this code to my header in Wordpress doesn't activate "allow_mobile_zooming"

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

should I be putting it into my functions.php file to load instead? Here's the code I'm using, it basically allows for finger zoom on mobile devices:

```
function allow_mobile_zooming() {
print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=10.0">';
print "\n";}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'allow_mobile_zooming', 9999999 );
```

thanks!

Comment: You might want to download the plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/definitely-allow-mobile-zooming/

Comment: Thanks Adam I already did, was trying to hard-code it and eliminate as many plugins as I could. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding this to your header.php, you can write it as html and not php:

Or you could add it to functions.php as you've written.  That code looks correct.

But it doesn't really make sense to add that code into header.php, since all it's doing is calling a hook to add it back into the header.  And if you place that code in header.php AFTER wp_head(), then it definitely won't work as the wp_head has already been called.

Comment: Thanks! added to functions.